# Removal confirm with a pop-up message (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement

I have a button with class `.delete`
When I click it I want to run a jQuery code.
First of all I want to do this:
`$('.pop-up-alert').addClass('clicked');`

Then I need to run a function with if/else if/else statments.

1. If `.no-btn` is clicked, I want to do this:
   `$('.pop-up-alert').removeClass('clicked');`
2. Else if `.yes-btn` clicked, I want to do this:
   `$(.delete).parent().remove();` // actually I need to delete only parent with `.delete` class child that was clicked (I need to use `this` somehow, but I don't know how)
3. Else, I'm apllying this code again:
   `$('.pop-up-alert').removeClass('clicked');`

The point is, if user clicks the delete button, he gets a pop-up with the ability to confirm deleting. If he clicks YES, jQuery will delete the `.delete` parent. If NO, pop-up will be hidden (with `.clicked` class in CSS). But if he clicks anywhere else, pop-up will be hidden anyway.

If I understand it right, the code should be something like that:

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
    $('.pop-up-alert').addClass('clicked');
    function() {
        if ($('.no-btn').click()) {
            $('.pop-up-alert').removeClass('clicked');
        } else if ($('.yes-btn').click()) {
            $(.delete).parent().remove();
        } else {
            $('.pop-up-alert').removeClass('clicked');          
        };
    };
});
```

But it doesn't work.
Please, help

Comment: Have you looked at jquery ui's [dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you simplify this? There is no need for `if { ... } else { ... }` statements. Just let jQuery detect click events, see my demo:

```js
// delete function
$('.delete').click(function() {

  var parent = $(this).parent(); // get parent of delete button
  $('.pop-up-alert').addClass('clicked'); // show the pop-up

  // if user clicks no
  $('.no-btn').click(function() {
    $('.pop-up-alert').removeClass('clicked'); // remove pop-up
  });

  // if user clicks yes
  $('.yes-btn').click(function() {
    parent.remove(); // delete parent
    $('.pop-up-alert').removeClass('clicked'); // hide pop-up
  });
});
```

```css
.pop-up-alert {
  display: none;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.pop-up-alert.clicked {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="pop-up-alert">
  Are you sure? <a href="#" class="no-btn">No</a> / <a href="#" class="yes-btn">Yes</a>
</div>

<div id="item1">Item 1 <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>
<div id="item2">Item 2 <a href="#" class="delete">Delete</a></div>
```

**[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/mdtsxf5t/)**

P.S your code was invalid because of this line: `$(.delete).parent().remove();` which should have been: `$('.delete').parent().remove();`